# Can we use swagger annotation values in our java code

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger

I am new to java. Trying to develop a application to schedule http api calls in a cron job. Only the method name will be the input. All the apis are configured with swagger annotations. Can I use these annotations to determine whether the api is post or get or delete etc. For example

```
  public class ABC {

    @ApiOperation(
          httpMethod = "GET",
          value = "value",
          notes = "notes",
          response = ABC.class)
    ABC getValue()
    {
    }
  }
```

only getValue is the input to my application. Can I get the @ApiOperation values to determine the http method type.

Comment: Yes, you can, but itt's not in this operation, it's in this one: `@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl",
     produces = { "application/json" },
     method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it is in the `RequestMapping` annotation (the one where you specify which URL should be linked to the method):

For example, this method will be called when someone navigates to `myBaseURl/persons` in GET. It will return JSON.

```
@ApiOperation(  value = "List of persons",
                notes = "List all my base's persons. ",
                response = Person.class,
                responseContainer = "List",
                tags = { "Persons", })
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons",
                produces = { "application/json" },
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public PagedResources<PersonResource> persons(...) {}
```